# Python re not extracting matched text based on regex while using boundary

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am extracting [this text from regex](https://regex101.com/r/h8NLhr/10), I matched required string in the text but while using python re to extract those matched text, its not extracting .

Here is the code I am using.

```
import re
PRICE = '\b(price|rs)?\s*(\d+[\s\d.]*\s*?(pkg|k|m| 
(?:la(?:c|kh|k)|crore|cr)s?|l)\b\.?)'

content ='This should matchprice  5.6 lacincluding price(i.e  price 
5.6 lac) and rs 56 m. including rs (i.e rs 56 k  rs 56 m) .

It will match normally if there is no price or rs written for example 
or   56 k or 8.8 crs. are correct matching.

It should not match5.6  lac (Should not match eitherrs 6 lac asas 
there is no spaces before 5.6'

for m in re.finditer(PRICE,content,pat.FLAG):
    matched = m.group().strip()
    print ("In matched "+ matched)`
```

Above code is not going inside the for loop. Any leads highly appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: Okay. I will mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use raw strings to define regexes:

```
PRICE = r'\b(price|rs)?\s*(\d+[\s\d.]*\s*?(pkg|k|m|(?:la(?:c|kh|k)|crore|cr)s?|l)\b\.?)'
```

Otherwise `\b` is interpreted as backspace:

```
>>> print '\b(price|rs)?\s*(\d+[\s\d.]*\s*?(pkg|k|m|(?:la(?:c|kh|k)|crore|cr)s?|l)\b\.?)'
(price|rs)?\s*(\d+[\s\d.]*\s*?(pkg|k|m|(?:la(?:c|kh|k)|crore|cr)s?|l\.?)
>>> print r'\b(price|rs)?\s*(\d+[\s\d.]*\s*?(pkg|k|m|(?:la(?:c|kh|k)|crore|cr)s?|l)\b\.?)'
\b(price|rs)?\s*(\d+[\s\d.]*\s*?(pkg|k|m|(?:la(?:c|kh|k)|crore|cr)s?|l)\b\.?)
```

Note how the first `print` output does not contain the initial `\b`. Keep in mind that the string is first interpreted by the python compiler, which means all usual escapes like `\n` for newline or `\b` for backspace or `\x42` for `B` are handled. The resulting string is then passed to the `re` module which interprets its own escapes. Hence in 99.9% of the cases you want to avoid that the compiler interprets escapes. The raw strings do just that.

The regex101 site assumes you are using raw string literals.